# Macros defined in _newlib_version.h are not filled with actual value

Tags: toolchain, newlib

Platform: Ubuntu22.04 for wsl2

I am trying to check some Macros defined in `_newlib_version.h`,  but I found that they are not filled with actual value. The following is the code snippet from the file  `/opt/riscv-newlib/riscv64-unknown-elf/include/_newlib_version.h`.

```c
/* _newlib_version.h.  Generated from _newlib_version.hin by configure.  */
/* Version macros for internal and downstream use. */
#ifndef _NEWLIB_VERSION_H__
#define _NEWLIB_VERSION_H__ 1

/* The newlib version in string format. */
#define _NEWLIB_VERSION "@NEWLIB_VERSION@"

/* The newlib major version number. */
#define __NEWLIB__ @NEWLIB_MAJOR_VERSION@

/* The newlib minor version number. */
#define __NEWLIB_MINOR__ @NEWLIB_MINOR_VERSION@

/* The newlib patch level. */
#define __NEWLIB_PATCHLEVEL__ @NEWLIB_PATCHLEVEL_VERSION@

#endif /* !_NEWLIB_VERSION_H__ */
```

I git clone the branch `master`, and I follow [Installation (Newlib/Linux multilib)](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain#installation-newliblinux-multilib) to install the toolchain. According to the comment  `_newlib_version.h.  Generated from _newlib_version.hin by configure.`, I think that `@xxx@` should be replaced when I `make`. Do I neglect anything?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm just glad I'm not the only one rn ^^'

Comment: I fear it's a problem from the rebuilt build system of newlib, I wrote a mail to the ML.

Comment: Apparently a fix was pushed:

https://sourceware.org/pipermail/newlib/2022/019864.html

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=newlib-cygwin.git;a=commitdiff;h=64a11fded15b92b56b91d65fd5b2851245f69299